# CodeIgniter select and display result in view

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have the following simple code:
The model:

```
function get_last_ten_entries()         
{
    $this->db->get('property');
}
```

controller:

```
public function load_recent()
{
    $data['info'] = $this->propertymodel->get_last_ten_entries();
    $this->load->view('load_property', $data);
}
```

view:

```
<?
echo $data['id'];
?>
```

This is not working. Am sure i am doing something wrong because the error shown says

> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Notice
>
> Message: Undefined variable: data
>
> Filename: views/load_property.php
>
> Line Number: 2

Property is a table in the database in which there is a field called id. what's going wrong?

Thank you all

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To fix the error, you'll need to use `$info` in your view, rather than `$data` as your array indexes in your controller correspond to variables in your view.

`$this->db->get('property')` returns all rows in the table `property`, but your function name suggests that you are trying to get the last 10 entries. I suggest you read [CodeIgniter's Active Record documentation](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/active_record.html) for more information. You also need to `return` your query.

You need to generate results from you query. [CodeIgniter's Query Results documentation](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/results.html) provides useful information on how to use the results of your query. What you're trying to achieve is a bit vague but you code could look something like this:

**Model**

```
function get_last_ten_entries()         
{
    return $this->db->get('property');  //Perform query (you'll need to update to select what you actually want from you database)
}
```

**Controller**

```
public function load_recent()
{
    $data['last_entries'] = $this->propertymodel->get_last_ten_entries();
    $this->load->view('load_property', $data);
}
```

**View**

```
foreach ($last_entries->result_array() as $entry)
{
   echo $entry['id'];
}
```

Or, if you rather use an object, instead of an array:

```
foreach ($last_entries->result() as $entry)
{
   echo $entry->id;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the simplification of the instructions above. I tried it exactly as given above, but screen returns blank. that is when I load domain.com/index.php/property/load_recent/. Appreciate the support

Answer (score 2):

first of all, your function in model dosen't return anything. try this:

```
function get_last_ten_entries()         
{
    $result = $this->db->get('property');
    return $result->result_array();
}
```

when you fix that, you will have variable $info available in your view because Codeigniter evaluates given array to distinct variables on `load->view( $view, $givenarray);`

example

```
$data['variable1'] = 'first var';
$data['array'] = array('id' => 1, 'name' => 'myname' );
$this->load-view('view', $data);
```

would let you use variables in view file as following

```
echo $variable1; // echoes 'first var';
echo $array['name']; // echoes myname
```